# Query from table based on some condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a scenario like this, there are 2 tables table_1 and table_2. Both table have a common column called column_1(no foreign_Key constraints!!). Table_1 can have some extra rows which are not present in table_2(In other words, table_2 is a sub-set of table_1). I want to list all those items which are only present in table_1 but not in table_2. 
Kindly help in writing the sql query for the same.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM   table1 a
       LEFT JOIN table2 b
           on a.column_1 = b.column_1
WHERE b.column_1 IS NULL
```

if those two tables are not related with each other, better add an index on `table1.column_1` and `table2.column_1` so that it won't require full table scan (*which slows the performance*)

Answer (score 1):

```
 select * from table1 
 inner join table2 on table1.column1=table2.column1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.* from table1 a left outer join table2 b on a.col1=b.col1;
```